# how to localize parsing data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, localization

I am working on localizations. I got some information regarding it i.e, editing  label text in Localizable.strings. But i want to localize parsing data. I am using below for editing label text in Localizable.strings. Any idea on this?

```
label1.text=NSLocalizedString(@"One", @"The Number1");
label2.text=NSLocalizedString(@"Two", @"The Number 2");
```

.....

```
Data is editing in 
 /* The Number 5 */
 "Five" = "Five";

/* The Number 4 */
"Four" = "Four";

/* The Number1 */
"One" = "One";

/* The Number 3 */
"Three" = "Three";

/* The Number 2 */
"Two" = "Two";
```

Comment: how to localize parsing data in table

Comment: What "parsing data" are you talking about? The strings file you show above is how you localize strings.

Comment: In your parsing data both keys and values are in your required language no?

Comment: The code  shown above is  for only editing labels but i now want to localize parsing data @ Cocoanetics

Comment: I want values which displays in table changes to required language @Anusha

Comment: If the keys also different for different languages you can store keys in the Localizable.strings.. and according to language you can get values..

Comment: @Anusha how to get values dynamically.generally in Localizable.strings we change data according to language.

Comment: Check the example given below..

Answer (score 1):

See this example :

In `Localizable.strings(English)` :

```
"Home" = "Home";
```

In `Localizable.strings(Danish)` :

```
"Home" = "Hjem";
```

Get key from `Localizable.strings` :

```
currentKey = NSLocalizedString(@"Home", nil);
```

Let in your yourParseDataDictionary :

```
value = "ABCD" for key = Home
value = "EFGH" for key = Hjem
```

Then you can get value as :

```
currentValue = [yourParseDataDictionary objectForKey:currentKey];

// currentValue = [yourParseDataDictionary objectForKey:@"Home"]; // In english
// currentValue = [yourParseDataDictionary objectForKey:@"Hjem"]; // In Danish
```